# How to add header and footer to the design using express-handlebars in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-handlebars

I have an issue regarding the rendering of other template on the existing one.

Let's say I have some design. So on main.handlebars I have wrote the Header and footer html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    .... load some css
</head>
<body>
    <div>So let's say this is the Header div</div>
    {{body}}
    <div>This is the footer div</div>
</body>
```

with this everything is fine. Now I want to add admin panel on this project. For that I picked the bootstrap template.

Now I want when I open admin panel through some URL, then all these header and footer are removed from handlebars. Currently everything is overwrite by the Header and footer.
Different Css will collide with each other.

Please provide me the optimum way/solution to tackle this situation